# rcharts and d3 plots not working together

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shiny, rcharts

I have a dashboard where 1 tab is using a plot created by rchart library and other tab is creating a word cloud using d3 js.
Unfortunately, my rChart is not showing and is generating this error:

```
TypeError: d3.select(...).append(...).datum is not a function
.datum(data)
```

But if I remove the word cloud tab in the ui.R then my rChart plot starts showing.
There is some conflict when I try to show both the tabs in my ui.r file.
I am running my shiny app on the shiny server. So, the directory structure is

```
/myapp 
  ui.r
  server.r
  cloud.js
/assets
  /www
   /js
     d3.js
     d3.layout.cloud.js
```

Here is my ui.r:

> ```
> require(rCharts)
> reactiveNetwork <- function (outputId) 
> {  
>   HTML(paste("<div id=\"", outputId, "\" class=\"shiny-network-output\"></svg></div>", sep=""))  
> }
>
> shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
>   headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R | NVD3"),
>
>   sidebarPanel(
>     selectInput(inputId = "gender",
>                 label = "Choose Gender",
>                 choices = c("Male", "Female"),
>                 selected = "Male"),
>     selectInput(inputId = "type",
>                 label = "Choose Chart Type",
>                 choices = c("multiBarChart", "multiBarHorizontalChart"),
>                 selected = "multiBarChart"),
>     checkboxInput(inputId = "stack",
>                   label = strong("Stack Bars?"),
>                   value = FALSE)
>   ),
>   mainPanel(
>     tabsetPanel(
>       tabPanel("rchart",
>                showOutput("myChart", "nvd3")),
>
>             tabPanel("d3",
>                h6("click on the word to see chat sessions related to it"),
>
>                includeHTML("cloud.js"),
>                reactiveNetwork(outputId = "cloud")
>
>
>      )
>
>       ) #tabPanel
>
>   )#mainPanel
> ))
> ```

server.r

> ```
> require(rCharts)
> shinyServer(function(input, output) {
>
>   output$myChart <- renderChart({
>     hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
>     p6 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == "Male"), 
>                 type = "multiBarChart", dom = 'myChart', width = 800)
>     #    p6$chart(color = c('brown', 'blue', '#594c26', 'green'), stacked = input$stack)
>     return(p6)
>   })
>   output$cloud <- reactivePlot(function(){
>
>   })
> })
> ```

cloud.js

> ```
> <script src="../assets/www/js/D3.js"></script>
> <script src="../assets/www/js/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
>
> <script>
> var networkOutputBinding2 = new Shiny.OutputBinding();
>   $.extend(networkOutputBinding2, {
>     find: function(scope) {
>       return $(scope).find('.shiny-network-output');
>     },
>     renderValue: function(el, value) {
>     var frequency_list = [{"text":"study","size":40},{"text":"motion","size":15},{"text":"forces","size":10},{"text":"electricity","size":15},{"text":"movement","size":10},{"text":"relation","size":5},{"text":"things","size":10},{"text":"force","size":5},{"text":"ad","size":5},{"text":"energy","size":85},{"text":"living","size":5},{"text":"nonliving","size":5},{"text":"laws","size":15},{"text":"speed","size":45},{"text":"velocity","size":30},{"text":"define","size":5},{"text":"constraints","size":5},{"text":"universe","size":10},{"text":"physics","size":120},{"text":"describing","size":5},{"text":"matter","size":90},{"text":"physics-the","size":5},{"text":"world","size":10},{"text":"works","size":10},{"text":"science","size":70},{"text":"interactions","size":30},{"text":"studies","size":5},{"text":"properties","size":45},{"text":"nature","size":40},{"text":"branch","size":30},{"text":"concerned","size":25},{"text":"source","size":40},{"text":"google","size":10},{"text":"defintions","size":5},{"text":"two","size":15},{"text":"grouped","size":15},{"text":"traditional","size":15},{"text":"fields","size":15},{"text":"acoustics","size":15},{"text":"optics","size":15},{"text":"mechanics","size":20},{"text":"thermodynamics","size":15},{"text":"electromagnetism","size":15},{"text":"modern","size":15},{"text":"extensions","size":15},{"text":"thefreedictionary","size":15},{"text":"interaction","size":15},{"text":"org","size":25},{"text":"answers","size":5},{"text":"natural","size":15},{"text":"objects","size":5},{"text":"treats","size":10},{"text":"acting","size":5},{"text":"department","size":5},{"text":"gravitation","size":5},{"text":"heat","size":10},{"text":"light","size":10},{"text":"magnetism","size":10},{"text":"modify","size":5},{"text":"general","size":10},{"text":"bodies","size":5},{"text":"philosophy","size":5},{"text":"brainyquote","size":5},{"text":"words","size":5},{"text":"ph","size":5},{"text":"html","size":5},{"text":"lrl","size":5},{"text":"zgzmeylfwuy","size":5},{"text":"subject","size":5},{"text":"distinguished","size":5},{"text":"chemistry","size":5},{"text":"biology","size":5},{"text":"includes","size":5},{"text":"radiation","size":5},{"text":"sound","size":5},{"text":"structure","size":5},{"text":"atoms","size":5},{"text":"including","size":10},{"text":"atomic","size":10},{"text":"nuclear","size":10},{"text":"cryogenics","size":10},{"text":"solid-state","size":10},{"text":"particle","size":10},{"text":"plasma","size":10},{"text":"deals","size":5},{"text":"merriam-webster","size":5},{"text":"dictionary","size":10},{"text":"analysis","size":5},{"text":"conducted","size":5},{"text":"order","size":5},{"text":"understand","size":5},{"text":"behaves","size":5},{"text":"en","size":5},{"text":"wikipedia","size":5},{"text":"wiki","size":5},{"text":"physics-","size":5},{"text":"physical","size":5},{"text":"behaviour","size":5},{"text":"collinsdictionary","size":5},{"text":"english","size":5},{"text":"time","size":35},{"text":"distance","size":35},{"text":"wheels","size":5},{"text":"revelations","size":5},{"text":"minute","size":5},{"text":"acceleration","size":20},{"text":"torque","size":5},{"text":"wheel","size":5},{"text":"rotations","size":5},{"text":"resistance","size":5},{"text":"momentum","size":5},{"text":"measure","size":10},{"text":"direction","size":10},{"text":"car","size":5},{"text":"add","size":5},{"text":"traveled","size":5},{"text":"weight","size":5},{"text":"electrical","size":5},{"text":"power","size":5}];
>
> console.log(frequency_list);
>     var color = d3.scale.linear()
>             .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,20,100])
>             .range(["#ddd", "#ccc", "#bbb", "#aaa", "#999", "#888", "#777", "#666", "#555", "#444", "#333", "#222"]);
>
>
>     d3.layout.cloud().size([800, 300])
>             .words(frequency_list)
>             .rotate(0)
>             .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
>             .on("end", draw)
>             .start();
>
>     function draw(words) {
>         d3.select(el).append("svg")
>                 .attr("width", 550)
>                 .attr("height", 350)
>                 .attr("class", "wordcloud")
>                 .append("g")
>                 // without the transform, words words would get cutoff to the left and top, they would
>                 // appear outside of the SVG area
>                 .attr("transform", "translate(320,200)")
>                 .selectAll("text")
>                 .data(words)
>                 .enter().append("text")
>                 .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
>                 .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
>                 .attr("transform", function(d) {
>                     return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
>                 })
>                 .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
>     }
>     }  
>   });
>   Shiny.outputBindings.register(networkOutputBinding2, 'timelyportfolio.networkbinding');
> </script>
> ```

d3.cloud.layout.js

> ```
> // Word cloud layout by Jason Davies, http://www.jasondavies.com/word-cloud/
> // Algorithm due to Jonathan Feinberg, http://static.mrfeinberg.com/bv_ch03.pdf
> (function() {
>   function cloud() {
>     var size = [256, 256],
>         text = cloudText,
>         font = cloudFont,
>         fontSize = cloudFontSize,
>         fontStyle = cloudFontNormal,
>         fontWeight = cloudFontNormal,
>         rotate = cloudRotate,
>         padding = cloudPadding,
>         spiral = archimedeanSpiral,
>         words = [],
>         timeInterval = Infinity,
>         event = d3.dispatch("word", "end"),
>         timer = null,
>         cloud = {};
>
>     cloud.start = function() {
>       var board = zeroArray((size[0] >> 5) * size[1]),
>           bounds = null,
>           n = words.length,
>           i = -1,
>           tags = [],
>           data = words.map(function(d, i) {
>             d.text = text.call(this, d, i);
>             d.font = font.call(this, d, i);
>             d.style = fontStyle.call(this, d, i);
>             d.weight = fontWeight.call(this, d, i);
>             d.rotate = rotate.call(this, d, i);
>             d.size = ~~fontSize.call(this, d, i);
>             d.padding = padding.call(this, d, i);
>             return d;
>           }).sort(function(a, b) { return b.size - a.size; });
>
>       if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
>       timer = setInterval(step, 0);
>       step();
>
>       return cloud;
>
>       function step() {
>         var start = +new Date,
>             d;
>         while (+new Date - start < timeInterval && ++i < n && timer) {
>           d = data[i];
>           d.x = (size[0] * (Math.random() + .5)) >> 1;
>           d.y = (size[1] * (Math.random() + .5)) >> 1;
>           cloudSprite(d, data, i);
>           if (d.hasText && place(board, d, bounds)) {
>             tags.push(d);
>             event.word(d);
>             if (bounds) cloudBounds(bounds, d);
>             else bounds = [{x: d.x + d.x0, y: d.y + d.y0}, {x: d.x + d.x1, y: d.y + d.y1}];
>             // Temporary hack
>             d.x -= size[0] >> 1;
>             d.y -= size[1] >> 1;
>           }
>         }
>         if (i >= n) {
>           cloud.stop();
>           event.end(tags, bounds);
>         }
>       }
>     }
>
>     cloud.stop = function() {
>       if (timer) {
>         clearInterval(timer);
>         timer = null;
>       }
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.timeInterval = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return timeInterval;
>       timeInterval = x == null ? Infinity : x;
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     function place(board, tag, bounds) {
>       var perimeter = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: size[0], y: size[1]}],
>           startX = tag.x,
>           startY = tag.y,
>           maxDelta = Math.sqrt(size[0] * size[0] + size[1] * size[1]),
>           s = spiral(size),
>           dt = Math.random() < .5 ? 1 : -1,
>           t = -dt,
>           dxdy,
>           dx,
>           dy;
>
>       while (dxdy = s(t += dt)) {
>         dx = ~~dxdy[0];
>         dy = ~~dxdy[1];
>
>         if (Math.min(dx, dy) > maxDelta) break;
>
>         tag.x = startX + dx;
>         tag.y = startY + dy;
>
>         if (tag.x + tag.x0 < 0 || tag.y + tag.y0 < 0 ||
>             tag.x + tag.x1 > size[0] || tag.y + tag.y1 > size[1]) continue;
>         // TODO only check for collisions within current bounds.
>         if (!bounds || !cloudCollide(tag, board, size[0])) {
>           if (!bounds || collideRects(tag, bounds)) {
>             var sprite = tag.sprite,
>                 w = tag.width >> 5,
>                 sw = size[0] >> 5,
>                 lx = tag.x - (w << 4),
>                 sx = lx & 0x7f,
>                 msx = 32 - sx,
>                 h = tag.y1 - tag.y0,
>                 x = (tag.y + tag.y0) * sw + (lx >> 5),
>                 last;
>             for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
>               last = 0;
>               for (var i = 0; i <= w; i++) {
>                 board[x + i] |= (last << msx) | (i < w ? (last = sprite[j * w + i]) >>> sx : 0);
>               }
>               x += sw;
>             }
>             delete tag.sprite;
>             return true;
>           }
>         }
>       }
>       return false;
>     }
>
>     cloud.words = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return words;
>       words = x;
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.size = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return size;
>       size = [+x[0], +x[1]];
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.font = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return font;
>       font = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.fontStyle = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return fontStyle;
>       fontStyle = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.fontWeight = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return fontWeight;
>       fontWeight = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.rotate = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return rotate;
>       rotate = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.text = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return text;
>       text = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.spiral = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return spiral;
>       spiral = spirals[x + ""] || x;
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.fontSize = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return fontSize;
>       fontSize = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     cloud.padding = function(x) {
>       if (!arguments.length) return padding;
>       padding = d3.functor(x);
>       return cloud;
>     };
>
>     return d3.rebind(cloud, event, "on");
>   }
>
>   function cloudText(d) {
>     return d.text;
>   }
>
>   function cloudFont() {
>     return "serif";
>   }
>
>   function cloudFontNormal() {
>     return "normal";
>   }
>
>   function cloudFontSize(d) {
>     return Math.sqrt(d.value);
>   }
>
>   function cloudRotate() {
>     return (~~(Math.random() * 6) - 3) * 30;
>   }
>
>   function cloudPadding() {
>     return 1;
>   }
>
>   // Fetches a monochrome sprite bitmap for the specified text.
>   // Load in batches for speed.
>   function cloudSprite(d, data, di) {
>     if (d.sprite) return;
>     c.clearRect(0, 0, (cw << 5) / ratio, ch / ratio);
>     var x = 0,
>         y = 0,
>         maxh = 0,
>         n = data.length;
>     --di;
>     while (++di < n) {
>       d = data[di];
>       c.save();
>       c.font = d.style + " " + d.weight + " " + ~~((d.size + 1) / ratio) + "px " + d.font;
>       var w = c.measureText(d.text + "m").width * ratio,
>           h = d.size << 1;
>       if (d.rotate) {
>         var sr = Math.sin(d.rotate * cloudRadians),
>             cr = Math.cos(d.rotate * cloudRadians),
>             wcr = w * cr,
>             wsr = w * sr,
>             hcr = h * cr,
>             hsr = h * sr;
>         w = (Math.max(Math.abs(wcr + hsr), Math.abs(wcr - hsr)) + 0x1f) >> 5 << 5;
>         h = ~~Math.max(Math.abs(wsr + hcr), Math.abs(wsr - hcr));
>       } else {
>         w = (w + 0x1f) >> 5 << 5;
>       }
>       if (h > maxh) maxh = h;
>       if (x + w >= (cw << 5)) {
>         x = 0;
>         y += maxh;
>         maxh = 0;
>       }
>       if (y + h >= ch) break;
>       c.translate((x + (w >> 1)) / ratio, (y + (h >> 1)) / ratio);
>       if (d.rotate) c.rotate(d.rotate * cloudRadians);
>       c.fillText(d.text, 0, 0);
>       if (d.padding) c.lineWidth = 2 * d.padding, c.strokeText(d.text, 0, 0);
>       c.restore();
>       d.width = w;
>       d.height = h;
>       d.xoff = x;
>       d.yoff = y;
>       d.x1 = w >> 1;
>       d.y1 = h >> 1;
>       d.x0 = -d.x1;
>       d.y0 = -d.y1;
>       d.hasText = true;
>       x += w;
>     }
>     var pixels = c.getImageData(0, 0, (cw << 5) / ratio, ch / ratio).data,
>         sprite = [];
>     while (--di >= 0) {
>       d = data[di];
>       if (!d.hasText) continue;
>       var w = d.width,
>           w32 = w >> 5,
>           h = d.y1 - d.y0;
>       // Zero the buffer
>       for (var i = 0; i < h * w32; i++) sprite[i] = 0;
>       x = d.xoff;
>       if (x == null) return;
>       y = d.yoff;
>       var seen = 0,
>           seenRow = -1;
>       for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
>         for (var i = 0; i < w; i++) {
>           var k = w32 * j + (i >> 5),
>               m = pixels[((y + j) * (cw << 5) + (x + i)) << 2] ? 1 << (31 - (i % 32)) : 0;
>           sprite[k] |= m;
>           seen |= m;
>         }
>         if (seen) seenRow = j;
>         else {
>           d.y0++;
>           h--;
>           j--;
>           y++;
>         }
>       }
>       d.y1 = d.y0 + seenRow;
>       d.sprite = sprite.slice(0, (d.y1 - d.y0) * w32);
>     }
>   }
>
>   // Use mask-based collision detection.
>   function cloudCollide(tag, board, sw) {
>     sw >>= 5;
>     var sprite = tag.sprite,
>         w = tag.width >> 5,
>         lx = tag.x - (w << 4),
>         sx = lx & 0x7f,
>         msx = 32 - sx,
>         h = tag.y1 - tag.y0,
>         x = (tag.y + tag.y0) * sw + (lx >> 5),
>         last;
>     for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
>       last = 0;
>       for (var i = 0; i <= w; i++) {
>         if (((last << msx) | (i < w ? (last = sprite[j * w + i]) >>> sx : 0))
>             & board[x + i]) return true;
>       }
>       x += sw;
>     }
>     return false;
>   }
>
>   function cloudBounds(bounds, d) {
>     var b0 = bounds[0],
>         b1 = bounds[1];
>     if (d.x + d.x0 < b0.x) b0.x = d.x + d.x0;
>     if (d.y + d.y0 < b0.y) b0.y = d.y + d.y0;
>     if (d.x + d.x1 > b1.x) b1.x = d.x + d.x1;
>     if (d.y + d.y1 > b1.y) b1.y = d.y + d.y1;
>   }
>
>   function collideRects(a, b) {
>     return a.x + a.x1 > b[0].x && a.x + a.x0 < b[1].x && a.y + a.y1 > b[0].y && a.y + a.y0 < b[1].y;
>   }
>
>   function archimedeanSpiral(size) {
>     var e = size[0] / size[1];
>     return function(t) {
>       return [e * (t *= .1) * Math.cos(t), t * Math.sin(t)];
>     };
>   }
>
>   function rectangularSpiral(size) {
>     var dy = 4,
>         dx = dy * size[0] / size[1],
>         x = 0,
>         y = 0;
>     return function(t) {
>       var sign = t < 0 ? -1 : 1;
>       // See triangular numbers: T_n = n * (n + 1) / 2.
>       switch ((Math.sqrt(1 + 4 * sign * t) - sign) & 3) {
>         case 0:  x += dx; break;
>         case 1:  y += dy; break;
>         case 2:  x -= dx; break;
>         default: y -= dy; break;
>       }
>       return [x, y];
>     };
>   }
>
>   // TODO reuse arrays?
>   function zeroArray(n) {
>     var a = [],
>         i = -1;
>     while (++i < n) a[i] = 0;
>     return a;
>   }
>
>   var cloudRadians = Math.PI / 180,
>       cw = 1 << 11 >> 5,
>       ch = 1 << 11,
>       canvas,
>       ratio = 1;
>
>   if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
>     canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
>     canvas.width = 1;
>     canvas.height = 1;
>     ratio = Math.sqrt(canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data.length >> 2);
>     canvas.width = (cw << 5) / ratio;
>     canvas.height = ch / ratio;
>   } else {
>     // Attempt to use node-canvas.
>     canvas = new Canvas(cw << 5, ch);
>   }
>
>   var c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
>       spirals = {
>         archimedean: archimedeanSpiral,
>         rectangular: rectangularSpiral
>       };
>   c.fillStyle = c.strokeStyle = "red";
>   c.textAlign = "center";
>
>   if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) module.exports = cloud;
>   else (d3.layout || (d3.layout = {})).cloud = cloud;
> })();
> ```

d3.js will be available from github incase you don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
There were 2 different versions of d3.js. I had to remove the other one.